# What does $Ho(Top,\pi_0^{-1}(\mathcal{W}))$ look like?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory

Consider the path components functor $\pi_0:Top\to Set$. Let  $\mathcal{W}$ be the wide subcategory which only contains the bijections. We know that $(Top,\pi_0^{-1}(\mathcal{W}))$ is a homotopical category.What does $Ho(Top,\pi_0^{-1}(\mathcal{W}))$ look like?

Ihaven't been able to figure this out.

Answer (score 4):

*Sketch of an answer* :

For any space $X$, there is a continuous map $\pi_0(X)^{dis}\to X$ where $A^{dis}$ is the set $A$ with the discrete topology, which sends each path component to one of its elements.

This map induces an iso on $\pi_0$.

Can you see why that implies that $\pi_0 : Top\to Set$ actually *is* the localization at $\pi_0^{-1}(\mathcal W)$ ?

Comment: isn't the map the other way around ? it should be the unit of an adjunction right ?

Comment: @jeanmfischer : I thought so too at first but the thing is, the map in the other direction isn't always continuous (it is if and only if the path components are open), whereas this one always is. $(-)^{dis}$ is left adjoint to the forgetful functor, not $\pi_0$ so there is no adjunction at play here.

Comment: (Though if you take e.g. locally connected spaces instead of all spaces, then you do have a chain of adjunctions $\pi_0 \dashv (-)^{dis} \dashv U$ ($U$ is the forgetful functor), and indeed you have a unit $id \to \pi_0^{dis}$, but this doesn't work for all spaces. If you take, e.g. $\mathbb Q$ with the usual topology, there is no initial map to discrete spaces, and in particular the canonical map $\mathbb Q\to \pi_0(\mathbb Q)$ is not continuous if you put the discrete topology on the right)

Comment: @jeanmfischer : yes, that works too, but you have to restrict. My answer (although the map is not natural in any way) shows that you can actually localize all spaces. A way to make your intuition work without restricting to specific spaces is to use an adjunction with locally connected spaces. If I recall correctly, David Roberts made a blog post about this adjunction, but it goes in the other direction, so you end up with a zigzag of weak equivalences which is natural, so I guess you can consider that to be a bit better

Comment: Let's work on simplicial sets :p thanks for the comments !

Comment: ( @jeanmfischer : for future reference : https://wildtopology.wordpress.com/2014/10/11/the-locally-path-connected-coreflection/   - it wasn't actually David Roberts, he just shared it on twitter ! What this implies is that there is a natural zigzag $\pi_0(lpc(X))^{dis} \leftarrow lpc(X) \to X$ where both arrows are $\pi_0$-isomorphisms. This still implies the desired conclusion and is indeed more natural, although it is a bit more involved ! )

Comment: Nice, thanks for the link !